When we post JSON data in ASP.NET API then derived class not mapped in model
I have this type of data and we have this EmployeeBonusDetail model class, and we map derived class model column in this model.
public  class EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int PointsEarned { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class CertificateBonusDetail : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string CertificateName { get; set; }
}

public class PolicyBonusDetail : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }
}

public class CUBenchBonusDetail : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
}

public class CoadingStandardDetails : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string CoadingStandardGrade { get; set; }
}

public class ClientInteractionDetails : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string VerbalCommunication { get; set; }
}

public class DomainKnowledgeBonusDetail : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeGradingBonusDetail : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public string Communication { get; set; }
    public int CommunicationPoint { get; set; }
    public string TeamCoordination { get; set; }
    public int TeamCoordinationPoint { get; set; }
    public string ProjectPerformance { get; set; }
    public int ProjectPerformancePoint { get; set; }
    public string Ownership { get; set; }
    public int OwnershipPoint { get; set; }
}

public class TraineeUnderTL
{
    public string tl_email { get; set; }
    public List<Trainee> trainees { get; set; }
}

public class Trainee : EmployeeBonusDetail
{
    public int trainee_emp { get; set; }
    public string trainee_name { get; set; }
    public string trainee_email { get; set; }
    public string trainee_skill { get; set; }
    public DateTime tl_assign_date { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeBonusDetailsRequest
{
    public List<EmployeeBonusDetailsResponse> EmployeeSkillDetails { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeSkillData> EmployeePointData { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeBonusDetailsResponse
{
    public string CategoryTable { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeBonusDetail> Data { get; set; }
}

But when we post data in this method, then derived classes columns are not mapped:
[Authorize]
[HttpPost(nameof(SaveGeneratedSkillBonusDetails))]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveGeneratedSkillBonusDetails([FromBody] EmployeeBonusDetailsRequest request)
{
    if (request == null || request.EmployeeSkillDetails == null || request.EmployeePointData == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid data received.");
    }

    try
    {
        var employeeSkillDetails = request.EmployeeSkillDetails;
        var employeePointData = request.EmployeePointData;

        // Save logic goes here

        return Ok(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}

Provide a solution to fix this problem, because when we post this model JSON data then show all data but derived class column is not mapped.

Are you using newtonsoft json or System.Text.JSON anywhere in your project

Do you expect instances of some subclass of EmployeeBonusDetail to be created when you post data that would be suitable for it? That is not supported by standard ASP .NET MVC model binding. How could it know what you want to happen...? You will need to construct a Custom Model Binder class. See e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324015/Custom-ASP-NET-Model-Binders-Series-Part-Subclassi

You could use a package to help you achieve bind the derived classes. You could install it from the nueget package and add below codes into the program.cs:
dotnet add package JsonSubTypes
and use NewtonsoftJson
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
Modify the program.cs :
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
        JsonSubtypesConverterBuilder
            .Of(typeof(EmployeeBonusDetail), "Type") // Specify discriminator property
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CertificateBonusDetail), "Certificate")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(PolicyBonusDetail), "Policy")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CUBenchBonusDetail), "Bench")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CoadingStandardDetails), "CodingStandard")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(ClientInteractionDetails), "ClientInteraction")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(DomainKnowledgeBonusDetail), "DomainKnowledge")
            .RegisterSubtype(typeof(EmployeeGradingBonusDetail), "Grading")
            .Build()
    );
});

Result:


For core2.2 , please try below codes:
   services.AddMvc()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
                JsonSubtypesConverterBuilder
                    .Of(typeof(EmployeeBonusDetail), "Type") // Specify discriminator property
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CertificateBonusDetail), "Certificate")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(PolicyBonusDetail), "Policy")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CUBenchBonusDetail), "Bench")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(CoadingStandardDetails), "CodingStandard")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(ClientInteractionDetails), "ClientInteraction")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(DomainKnowledgeBonusDetail), "DomainKnowledge")
                    .RegisterSubtype(typeof(EmployeeGradingBonusDetail), "Grading")
                    .Build()
            );
        });


in my application Framework is netcoreapp2.2 version, Services.AddControllers() so this is not working in my application.

this is not work in .Net core 2.2 version

firstly, .net core 2.2 is too old, please use the newest .net core version, besides, since I don't have the .net core 2.2 , I could just provide some codes   and you need test it by yourself.
